go-redis FTSearch returns empty result
I'm able to create an index and load data using go-redis. Also, I'm able to search but only via CLI. That means the index is created properly and is searchable. It returns the correct results.
But when I try to search the data programmatically, it returns:
redis: 2024/07/26 19:27:10 pool.go:368: Conn has unread data
{Total:0 Docs:[]}

I'm using the following example: https://github.com/redis/go-redis/blob/master/search_test.go#L128-L138
Code used for reference:
// Create index
_, err := client.FTCreate(ctx, "txt", &redis.FTCreateOptions{}, &redis.FieldSchema{FieldName: "txt", FieldType: redis.SearchFieldTypeText}).Result()

// Add data
client.HSet(ctx, "doc1", "txt", "foo baz")
client.HSet(ctx, "doc2", "txt", "foo bar")

// Search
res, err := client.FTSearchWithArgs(ctx, "txt", "foo ~bar", &redis.FTSearchOptions{WithScores: true, Limit: 50}).Result()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\nerr: %v", err)
}

The same goes for client.JSONSet. Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here?

Change the protocol to 2 when creating the client - the following code works:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
)

var ctx = context.Background()

func main() {
    var client *redis.Client

    client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Protocol: 2, // this right here
    })

    _, err := client.FTCreate(ctx, "txt", &redis.FTCreateOptions{}, &redis.FieldSchema{FieldName: "txt", FieldType: redis.SearchFieldTypeText}).Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\nerr: %v", err)
    }

    // Add data
    client.HSet(ctx, "doc1", "txt", "foo baz")
    client.HSet(ctx, "doc2", "txt", "foo bar")

    // Search
    res, err := client.FTSearchWithArgs(ctx, "txt", "foo ~bar", &redis.FTSearchOptions{WithScores: true, Limit: 50}).Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\nerr: %v", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\nRetrieved :%d documents", len(res.Docs))
    }
}


It looks like there's something wrong with how the go redis client is reading the results when it's interfacing with Redis over RESP3 which is the default for the redis go client.

That solved the problem! TY!
